# How to expose node binary to electron app without install node

Tags: electron

I build an Electron app with plugin system based on yarn (installed as node module), since I don't want to force users to install node or npm.

Some plugins depends on modules with postinstall script "node index.js".
This script failed because node doesn't exists.

Since Electron contains some version of node I thought to add the directory with electron's node to PATH, but I can't find the node binary in packaged app.

I missed something?
Can you think about any other workaround?

I use electron-packager on mac.

I don't think it's relevant to issue but here the main part of install function:

```js
var modulePath = join(__dirname, '../', 'node_modules', 'yarn', 'bin', 'yarnpkg')
var args = ['add', `${plugin.name}@${plugin.version}`, '--json' ]
var child = fork(modulePath, args ,{ silent: true, cwd: this.pluginsPath })
```

process info:

```js
{
  "PATH": "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
  "versions": {
    "http_parser": "2.7.0",
    "node": "6.5.0",
    "v8": "5.3.332.45",
    "uv": "1.9.1",
    "zlib": "1.2.8",
    "ares": "1.10.1-DEV",
    "modules": "50",
    "openssl": "1.0.2h",
    "electron": "1.4.5",
    "chrome": "53.0.2785.113",
    "atom-shell": "1.4.5"
  }
}
```